# mod_python and Apache 2.4

Tags: python, apache2

I have upgraded my server from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04.
Everything is ok, but there is used Apache 2.4. But mod python require Apache 2.2 :(

I have old version of trac (issue tracking system).
Is there any way how to make it works on new Apache 2.4 ?

Previous configureation is

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
DocumentRoot /srv/www/trac
ServerName trac.local.net
<Location />
    SetHandler mod_python
    PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
    PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
    PythonOption TracEnv /srv/www/trac/env
    PythonOption TracUriRoot /
</Location>
<Location /login>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "MyCompany Trac Server"
    AuthUserFile /srv/www/trac/htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
PythonDebug on
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest mod_python (3.5.0) from http://modpython.org/ supports Apache 2.4 (and also Python 3).

In the case of the OP, you're probably better off running mod_wsgi, if all you need is Trac. But for anyone actually depending on mod_python, just upgrade it. Unfortunately there are no .debs, you'll have to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to avoid using mod_python. Use [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) instead.

`mod_python` has been deprecated and it no longer has support.